# How to find Radius of convergence for power series whose coefficients are defined recursively

Tags: sequences-and-series

P1 : The Radius of convergence of power series whose nth term is given by $a_n{z^{n^2}}$ where $a_0 = 1 $ , $ a_n = 3^{-n} (a_{n-1})$

P2 :Given $a_n ={1/3^n} $, if n is prime
                $a_n = 1/4^n$ , if n is not prime

Then radius of convergence of power series whose nth term is given by $a_nx^{n}$

Comment: What methods to obtain the radius of convergence from the coefficients do you know?

Comment: ratio,root and other method same as used in infinite series

Comment: Root is good. Try that.

Comment: Any ideas  for P2

Comment: Root test, really. It works.

Comment: that is fine . im having problem with way it is defined . on applying root test radius of cvgence re 3 nd 4 . so what to do from here .pls clarify

Comment: I fear, I fear. What form of the root test have you been taught?

Comment: the coefficients are defined as when n is prime and when n is not prime . so shoudnt we get two values of R for each case

Comment: No, there is only one radius of convergence for any power series. What is $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \lvert a_n z^n\rvert^{1/n}\,?$$

Comment: you are saying abour P1 . im talking about P2

Comment: What makes you believe I'm talking about P1? (Actually, what I'm saying also applies to P1, since it applies in general, but the point is, it applies to P2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P1) $a_n =3^{-1 -2 -...-n} a_0 =3^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} $ hence the radius $$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} 3^{-\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2n}}} =\sqrt{3}.$$

Comment: Any ideas for p2

Comment: For P2) We have $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n |} =\frac{1}{3}$$ hebce $$R=3.$$