# How to show this series is conditionally convergent $(-1)^{n+1}\log(n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would one show that the infinite series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\log(n+1)}$$ is conditionally convergent?

Tried ratio,root,nth ,logarithmic,condensation, but all in vain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $n>0$ it is clear (or can easily be proven) that $$e^n>n+1 \\ \implies n>\log(n+1) \\ \implies \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{\log(n+1)}$$ so clearly $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\log(n+1)}\right|$$ It is well known that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ is a divergent infinite series, so by the comparison test it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\log(n+1)}$ diverges absolutely. Now you just have to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\log(n+1)}$ converges and you will be done.

Comment: thanks ..how to prove 1st step

Comment: Which step do you mean?

Comment: e^n >n+1 . is there any other way also

Comment: That's a pretty easy proof by induction. Have you had experience with that?

Comment: yes yes i got the hint thankyou for your elegent solution..if u have time can u pls guie me through P2 of this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011049/how-to-find-radius-of-convergence-for-power-series-whose-coefficients-are-define?noredirect=1#comment2064800_1011049